# When to deregister for radio tax when doing abmeldung?

Tags: germany

When I deregister my German apartment, when should I deregister for the Rundfunkbeitrag? Or does it happen automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I deregister my German apartment, when should I deregister for the Rundfunkbeitrag?

Yes, after you deregister your German apartment.

Either scan in you deregisteration certificate or make a clear photo and add it within the last step of the [Abmelden Form](https://www.rundfunkbeitrag.de/buergerinnen_und_buerger/formulare/abmelden/index_ger.html) (jpg, png, tif, pdf - max 10 MB).

---

> **Dauerhafter Umzug ins Ausland**
> Sie können Ihr Rund­funk­beitrags­konto [abmelden](https://www.rundfunkbeitrag.de/buergerinnen_und_buerger/formulare/abmelden/index_ger.html), wenn Sie dauer­haft ins Aus­land ziehen und Ihre Wohnung in Deutsch­land voll­ständig auf­geben (Nach­weis über Ab­mel­dung beim Ein­wohner­melde­amt er­forder­lich).
>
> Wohnen außer Ihnen noch weitere Personen in der Wohnung? Dann muss die Wohnung von einer Person, die weiter­hin in der Wohnung ver­bleibt, zum Rund­funk­beitrag angemeldet werden.
>
> > **Permanent move abroad**
> > You can deregister your broadcasting contribution account if you move abroad permanently and completely give up your apartment in Germany (proof of deregistration at the residents' registration office is required).
> >
> > Are there any other people living in the apartment besides you?  The apartment must then be registered for the broadcasting fee by a person who remains in the apartment.

---

**Sources**:

- [Der Rundfunkbeitrag - Auslandsaufenthalt](https://www.rundfunkbeitrag.de/buergerinnen_und_buerger/informationen/auslandsaufenthalt/index_ger.html) (in German)

  - [Der Rundfunkbeitrag - Abmelden](https://www.rundfunkbeitrag.de/buergerinnen_und_buerger/formulare/abmelden/index_ger.html) (in German)